# Harley Benton HBO-850 Bass, electric or acoustic strings?

Tags: strings

I just bought the - [Harley Benton HBO-850 Bass from Thomann.](https://www.thomann.de/pt/harley_benton_hbo_850_bass_natural.htm)

I wanted to know which strings I should use: electric or acoustic? And some cheap string brands as well. I'd like to have a simple explanation about the difference between them if using them on this particular bass. Thank you.